# Set script src to dynamic value when inheriting from base template in flask

Tags: flask

So I have some flask code, and am wondering if there is any way to make the url inside the html dynamic. The flask code is as following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
application = app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In base.html, I have some code, and at the end, I have

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/base.js') }}"></script>
```

The code rendered results in:

```
<script src="/static/js/base.js"></script>
```

I'm having another html file inherit from base.html. index.html is below:

```
<h1>some code (the code doesn't really matter)</h1>
```

I want to be able to add a script tag at the end with it being `<script src="/static/js/base.js"></script>`, without adding anything. Is there any way to do that?

In other words, if the template is index.html, I want the script tag source to be index.js; if the template is challenge.html, I want the script tag source to be challenge.js.

Comment: You want to add this to index.html, not to the base template?  Is there a specific reason why not add this script to base template? Is there a specific reason why not using url_for? In general url_for in the preferred way.

Comment: What I want is that if the template is named index.html, the script tag is index.js. If the template is named challenge.html, the script tag is challenge.js, and I want all of that to extend from the base template so I don't have to manually add it to every template that inherits from the base template.

Comment: Can you explain what the difficulty is then? Lets say you create all those different js files and link them with url_for or hardlinking, doesn't that work? If not, what errors do you get? Why is it not possbile to create just 1 js file, add this to base template and all scripts in that file do their job, whatever that may be?

Comment: I didn't get any errors yet, but that's because I'm giving the base template a js file. Some of the buttons/divs in all of my pages that inherit from the base template have the same id, so the jquery would be broken if I put them all in the same javascript file. Also, I want to use this for css, and if on one page, I want all h1 to be red, and on the other, I want all the h1 to be black, I'd have to have separate css files.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to use unique ids. In that case if you want the same styling, use class (does not have to be unique) attribute, if not you can use unique id.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but I wanted to see if there was another solution out there (I already wrote all my code, and changing the ids might take a while). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The only alternative I see would be adding different js files to all child templates.

Comment: That solution works. I updated my post with the solution above. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jinja [assignments](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments) (template variables) in the parent and set them in the child.

base.html

```
{% set main_js = main_js|default('') %}
{% if main_js %}
    <script src="/static/js/{{ main_js }}.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% set main_js = 'index' %}
```

You can use the same technique for things like the page title, meta tags, etc.